# Angular 2 - how to download a JSON object

Tags: angular

If I click an icon I want to download a json object.  In Angular 2 how?

Here is my html:

```
<i class="material-icons" (click)="download(model.model_id)">file_download</i>
```

Here is my typescript:

```
  download(mid){

    let test = {"a":"b"}

    return test

  }
```

Comment: how do you have so much reputation and ask such a low quality question?

Comment: by now he should know about http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this is not a complete or verifiable example.

Comment: Please be more specific what you are trying to do. Do you want to allow a user to download a json file that is created dynamically? Please note, phrases like "json object" are meaningless as json and object are literally contradictions in terms. Json may be an object that had been serialized into a string or stream. It would then need to be deserealized to be an object again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a example component to export data into `.csv` file,it should help your needs.

Specially the `buildDownloader()` function is about how to create a downloader:
[csv-downloader.ts](https://gist.github.com/derekshi/2d4969c59627ab5aca65b37eaeab72fc)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the standard html attribute for download. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

`<a href="/path/to/file.json" download="nameOfFile.json" target='_blank'>`